# JMeter - I need to pass a parameter called "Cookie" in the request header

Tags: jmeter, session-cookies, request-headers

I am using apache jmeter 5.2.1 with Java 8 to perform the performance test in a JSF application.
I need to send in the header of an HTTP request a parameter called "Cookie" according to the example below:
[image]

I've tried several things but none work.
I have already used the HttpHeaderManager resource but apparently the word "Cookie" is a JMeter reserved word so I can't create a parameter in the Header with the name "Cookie".
If I create a parameter in HttpHeaderManager with any name it is appended to the request header, but if I create with the name "Cookie" which is the name I need to use JMeter simply ignore it and do not add it to the request header .

I saw many posts indicating that I used the following code snippet:

```
CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID",vars.get("jSessionId"),"${serveraddress}",false,0);
manager.add(cookie);
```

I've tested it but it doesn't work either, it returns the following error whenever I try to use it:
[image]

I also have an Http Cookie Manager but its value is sent in the request body and not in the header.

I also tried to use the Http Autorization Manager as I saw in some posts but it only works when the login is done at a prompt in the browser.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Nothing JSF related in this question. Session-Cookies are a servlet container thing and this is even not related to that but pure jmeter.

Comment: @Kukeltje This JSESSIONID was not actually from JSF.
As I am new to Jmeter and with JSF I didn't know.
Upon analyzing everything I had again I realized that my regular expression that extracts the ViewState from JSF was incorrect.
After correcting this regular expression the test worked normally.
Thanks to everyone who answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) to your Test Plan and it will automatically "manage" cookies for you (the HTTP Request samplers must be in the HTTP Cookie Manager's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules))

You can double check that JMeter sends correct [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header using a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

If you added the HTTP Cookie Manager but JMeter still doesn't send the JSESSIONID cookie it might be the case there is a problem with the cookie itself, i.e. it doesn't match domain/path or expired or your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration is not correct.

If you absolutely sure that your application behaves as expected you can configure JMeter to be less restrictive by:

1. Choosing a more "relaxed" cookie policy, i.e. `netscape`
2. Adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```
3. You can also add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
   ```

   this way you will get comprehensive information of the Cookie Manager's behaviour in the [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/)